# Auto-generated reset password is empty string in reset password email

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates, password-recovery

So we have a Magento webshop and we suddenly discovered that when you use the "forgot password" funtion, it sends an email with an empty password string.

Now I've looked through a lot of forums and questions but alas, I could not find anything.

I've looked in `app/locale/nl_NL/template/email/password_new.html`
And I saw the `{{htmlescape var=$customer.password}}` string.
This one is empty. I've tried some things which were logical to me:

```
{{htmlescape var=$user.password}}
{{htmlescape var=$password}}
```

Also, I'm starting to think it might be something else. Or some other template which handles this.

So my questions is, how do I fix this? Where do I look?
I am experienced with `PHP` so programming related answers are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've looked even deeper into the web for this problem.
I've found an article which solved my problem.

I removed the new password part and replaced it with some nice text and a link to reset your password.

So, go to your transactional emails, `system > transactional emails`.
Next, go to you forgot password template. Where the layout is that is send to the customer with the new password.

Next up, I created a link like so:

```
 Did you ask for a new password? Click <a href="{{store url=customer/account/resetpassword/ _query_id=$customer.id _query_token=$customer.rp_token}}">here</a>. <br> If not, please ignore this email.
```

Save the email, clear cache and reindex just to be sure, and try it again.

Now you get an email with the link so people can change it themselves.

Source: [Ashwin Vasava](https://vasavaa.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/magento-reset-customer-password-is-blank/)